# tracing an XML trace file and find index using python ET. trace

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I have an XML trace file and it has different tags. I am trying to find `X` and `Y` values in a file to calculate the motion vector.I put part of the file below:

```
<Picture id="1" poc="1">
    <GOPNr>0</GOPNr>
    <SubPicture structure="0">
        <Slice num="0">
            <Type>0</Type>
            <TypeString>SLICE_TYPE_P</TypeString>
            <NAL>
                <Num>6</Num>
                <Type>1</Type>
                <TypeString>NALU_TYPE_SLICE</TypeString>
                <Length>178927</Length>
            </NAL>
            <MacroBlock num="0">
                <Position>
                    <X>0</X>
                    <Y>0</Y>
                </Position>
                <QP_Y>23</QP_Y>
                <Type>5</Type>
                <TypeString>I_8x8</TypeString>
                <PredModeString>BLOCK_TYPE_I</PredModeString>
                <SkipFlag>0</SkipFlag>
            </MacroBlock>
```

this file has lots of `MacroBlock` tags but some of these tags have `MotionVector`. for extracting `X` and  `Y` values I used the following code:

```
abs_x_tag=list(qpy_node.text for qpy_node in root.findall('Picture/SubPicture/Slice/MacroBlock/SubMacroBlock/MotionVector/Absolute/X'))
```

I need to find the `X` and `Y` values related to specific `TypeString` but at one time I can just extract one value using the above code. for example, I need to find X and Y values related to `<TypeString>P` but I do not know how can I do this. could you please help me with this issue?
Thanks

Comment: I need to find out these x and y values are in which Picture and Macroblock, because I need to calculate a motion vector for just Macroblocks that the TypeStiring is P, right?

Comment: abs_x_tag contains all X values in the XML file but I need to find X values that the PredModeString in the Macroblock is Block_Type_P or Blcok_TYpe_B?

Comment: I need to separate these X values based on their block type.

Comment: there's no absolute/motionvector in this new code

Answer (score 0):

when you want to parse multiple values inside one block, particularly if you have to make decisions based on one or more of those values, parse by block. if you extract the values separately you lose the link between them

```
data="""<Picture><MacroBlock num="936">
                    <MotionVector list="0">
                        <Absolute>
                            <X>0</X>
                            <Y>0</Y>
                        </Absolute>
                    </MotionVector>
                    <TypeString>P_L0_16x16</TypeString>
                </MacroBlock>
                <MacroBlock num="937">
                    <MotionVector list="0">
                        <Absolute>
                            <X>1</X>
                            <Y>2</Y>
                        </Absolute>
                    </MotionVector>
                    <TypeString>B_L0_16x16</TypeString>
                </MacroBlock></Picture>"""
                
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root=ET.fromstring(data)
blocks=root.findall('MacroBlock')
for block in blocks:
    x=block.find('MotionVector/Absolute/X').text
    y=block.find('MotionVector/Absolute/Y').text
    type_string=block.find('TypeString').text[0]
    print(x, y, type_string)
>>> 0 0 P
>>> 1 2 B
```

Comment: I used your code but it produces this error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'" and I do not know what is the problem.

Comment: i think it's because there's a discrepancy between your real code and your xml example. i see some `SubMacroBlock` in your code where it's called `MacroBlock` in your xml

Comment: I do not have SubMacroBlock element. all elements that I have are as my above example. so I could not understand your comment?

Comment: in your code you have this `'Picture/SubPicture/Slice/MacroBlock/SubMacroBlock/MotionVector/Absolute/X'`

Comment: sorry, yes I have. some of the part do not have SubMacroBlock and some them have.so this means by having SubMacroBlock I can not find the things I want and there is no solution?